# Angular - Service injection

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a service (*modal-dialog.service*) that should be instantiated when the application starts. I added it to my general services folder with the `providedIn: 'root'` property. This service has to inject modal dialogs in the `<body>` tag, and has to accept a component type to be rendered in the modal dialog:

```
/**
 * Inject a dialog to the body.
 * @param dialogClass Class of the dialog.
 * @param configureDialog Configuration function for the dialog.
 */
public injectDialogToBody<T>(dialogClass: Type<T>, configureDialog: (dialogRef: ComponentRef<T>) => void): ComponentRef<T> {
    const factory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dialogClass);
    var dialogRefComponent = factory.create(this._injector);
    this._applicationRef.attachView(dialogRefComponent.hostView);
    configureDialog(dialogRefComponent);
    var dom = (dialogRefComponent.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0];
    document.body.appendChild(dom);
    return dialogRefComponent;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that, when I'm calling this `injectDialogToBody` method from a module passing it a component in that module so it is displayed inside the modal dialog, I get the error "*No component factory found for XXXComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?*".

Moving this *modal-dialog.service* to a common module inside the *modules* folder and adding it to the *providers* of that module fixes the problem. Why doesn't the service recognise the type of the component if placed inside the general *services* folder (outside the *modules* folder) and using the `providedIn: 'root'`?

Comment: You need to add dialogComponent to `entryComponents` array of your module

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your DialogComponent in the `entryComponents` of the Module where it is declared.

Following the Angular Documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader

You have to do like this example: 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DialogComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DialogComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogComponent
  ]
})
export class CustomModule {}
```

Comment: My DialogComponent is already added in the `entryComponents` of its module. But where it isn't added is to the `exports` one... I'll try adding it there.

Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Please, remember to mark the question as closed so tomorrow it will be a reference to another developer that can have the same issue as you.